# Change Company Domain name for next projects on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, configuration

Supporse I have a company domain `com.ernanni.br` and I want to change it in a way that every next project I create comes with a different name I want to, let's suppose `com.ernanni`.

Is there a way to change the Company Domain on Android Studio even for future projects? So I don't need to change every time I want to create a new project